# Is there anyway that I could use an if else statement in Spacy Matcher?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, matcher

I'm trying to use Spacy's Matcher on job requirements so i'm able to find the years of experience that an employer is looking for.

```
    doc = nlp("""
<ul><li>2-3 years working experience ideal but driven Fresh Grads are welcomed!</li><li>Create elegant and compelling designs for all of Dapat products and Social Media channels</li><li>Knowledge in Social Media / Digital Marketing is a PLUS!</li><li>You are a chameleon - Able to adapt to new challenges, working environments etc.</li><li>Ability to work on multiple projects, prioritize as needed and manage time in an efficient manner</li><li>Knowledge in Adobe Creative Suite / Cloud (Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign)</li><li>Knowledge in UI/UX tools like Sketch, Invision, Balsamiq - is also a PLUS!</li><li>You are an excellent team player and do not shy away from responsibilities and challenges&nbsp;</li><li>Organized, detail oriented and able to work independently on multiple projects</li><li>Proficiency with office productivity tools including email, web browsers, web apps, database search, spreadsheets/word processors (Google Apps)</li><li>Interest in and familiarity with current tech products</li></ul><div><br></div>
""")

# Initialize the Matcher with the shared vocabulary
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

# Create a pattern matching the tokens
pattern = [{'IS_DIGIT':True}, {"LEMMA": "year", 'POS':'NOUN'}]
pattern1 = [{'IS_DIGIT': True},{'TEXT':'-'},{'IS_DIGIT':True},{"LEMMA": "year", 'POS':'NOUN'}]
pattern2 = [{'IS_DIGIT': True},{'TEXT':'to'},{'IS_DIGIT':True},{"LEMMA": "year", 'POS':'NOUN'}]
pattern3 = [{'IS_DIGIT': True},{'TEXT':'or'},{'IS_DIGIT':True},{"LEMMA": "year", 'POS':'NOUN'}]
pattern4 = [{'IS_DIGIT': True},{'TEXT':'+'},{"LEMMA": "year", 'POS':'NOUN'}]
pattern5 = [{'IS_ALPHA': True},{'TEXT':'('},{'IS_DIGIT': True},{'TEXT':')'},{'TEXT':'to'},{'IS_ALPHA':True},{'TEXT':'('},{'IS_DIGIT': True},{'TEXT':')'},{"LEMMA": "year", 'POS':'NOUN'}]
pattern6 = [{'lower':'fresh grads'}]

# Add the pattern to the matcher
matcher.add("x years", None, pattern)
matcher.add("z - x years", None, pattern1)
matcher.add("z to x years", None, pattern2)
matcher.add("z or y years",None, pattern3)
matcher.add('x+ years', None, pattern4)
matcher.add('alpha(digit) to alpha(digit) years', None, pattern5)


# Use the matcher on the doc
matches = matcher(doc)
matched = [doc[start:end].text for match_id, start, end in matches]
print("Matches:", matched)
```

For the last pattern, pattern6, I'm trying to match fresh grads so when I do get fresh grads in the requirements, it would just print out 0 years of experience but if it doesn't, it would just print out anything that matches in the sentence. Is there anyway that I could use an if else statement where if pattern6 is triggered, then it would print matches: 0 years?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with the `Matcher` itself. You would need to run the matcher, analyze the results to see which patterns matched, and then output "0 years" if nothing was found (for example).

Also, remember that the `Matcher` patterns are for individual tokens, so `{"lower": "fresh grads"}` won't match anything because of the space in the middle. You'd need to split this into two token patterns.